# Why can't I create a multidimensional array of arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors, syntax-error

My program involves a 2-dimensional board: `Square[width,height]`. Each Square contains a collection of Pieces.

In the presentation layer, I want to only present the collection of Pieces in each Square and represent each Piece with its string Name. I.e. `string[][width,height]`.

Declaring `string[][,]` compiles with no problem but I can't initialize the variable:

```
string[][,] multiArrayOfArrays; //No problemo
multiArrayOfArrays = new string[][8,8]; //Generates errors
```

The following errors are generated for the second line:

```
CS1586  Array creation must have array size or array initializer    
CS0178  Invalid rank specifier: expected ',' or ']' ModChess    
CS0178  Invalid rank specifier: expected ',' or ']' ModChess
```

I'm currently using `List<string>[,]` as a workaround but the errors vex me. Why can I successfully declare a `string[][,]` but not initialize it?
Note: Using VS Community 16.0.4, C# 7.3.

Comment: Maybe use a `Dictionary<string, Size>` (or `Dictionary<string, Point>`) instead? Or a specialized class that can  handle different properties.

Comment: This looks like the [Primitive Obsession](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrimitiveObsession) antipattern; you're trying to model your data as a big bag of strings, expecting every consumer to reach inside and fiddle the strings around correctly. This almost always causes problems. Instead, create classes to represent your chessboard or whatever, and methods in those classes to make moves or whatever.

Comment: @DourHighArch Oof, this definitely looks like Primitive Obsession. I didn't even know that was a thing. For now, I'll keep the code as is and refactor when this layer gets more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want a `string[,][] a`.

```
string[,][] a = new string[3, 4][];
a[0, 0] = new string[10];
a[0, 1] = new string[4];
a[1, 0] = new string[6];
string s = a[0, 0][2];
```

You have a special case of a jagged array, where the first array is 2-dimensional. It contains one-dimensional arrays of different sizes as elements.

The ordering of the array brackets might seem wrong, as the element type is usually on the left side of the brackets; however, if you think about on how you want to access elements, then it makes sense. First, you want to specify the 2 coordinates of the 2-dimensional board, then the single index of the pieces collection.

---

According to [Jagged Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays), `int[][,] jaggedArray4 = new int[3][,]` *"...  is a declaration and initialization of a single-dimensional jagged array that contains three two-dimensional array elements of different sizes."*

Comment: This works as expected with minimal refactoring. Thanks!

I guess array initialization just has this weird quirk because it doesn't use parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

> string[][,] multiArrayOfArrays; //No problemo

Here you just declare variable of specific type.

> multiArrayOfArrays = new string[][8,8]; //Generates errors

And here you actually create new object of specific type. It generates errors because this is invalid syntax for multidimentional array initialization.

You need to specify size for first dimension `[]` and then initialize each element of that array with `string[,]`.

Think of it as array of arrays:

```cs
string[][,] multiArrayOfArrays; //No problemo
multiArrayOfArrays = new string[5][,];//create 5 elements of string[,] array
for (int i = 0; i < multiArrayOfArrays.Length; ++i)
{
    multiArrayOfArrays[i] = new string[8,8];//actually fill elements with string[8,8]
}
```

or

```cs
string[][,] multiArrayOfArrays; //No problemo
multiArrayOfArrays = new string[][,]
{
    new string[8,8],
    new string[8,8],
    new string[8,8],
};
```